# My ajax request is not working on first page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have dynamically loaded content `.task-listing`. The click works because it does "show" the div. But the ajax request doesnt function properly. I get a 200 status in the console, but I get no response from the server. If I refresh the page, it works properly. Why would this occur? I cant figure it out, I have been researching for over 2 hours. When I use firefox it doesnt happen again until I close the browser...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click", ".task-listing", function () {
    var info = $(this).attr("id");
    getTaskInfo(info);
    $(".task-data").show();
  });
});

function getTaskInfo(info) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/src/php/get-info-task.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "info=" + info,
    success: function (response) {
      alert("ok");
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: You are calling the `getTaskInfo` function, before loading it, which might cause race-conditions.. try adding it within  `$(document).ready(function(){` and before the on_click

Comment: @Ron That shouldn't be a problem. All function definitions are defined when the JS is parsed. And `$(document).ready()` doesn't execute the code until after everything is loaded.

Comment: Your braces aren't balanced here. Please post the whole function.

Comment: I suspect this is related to something else that your page does. `get-info-task.php` is expecting something, like a session variable, that isn't set until you reload the page.

Comment: The snippet you've posted is not enough to figure it out.